# Can't render date in template

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mainCtrl.items" class="item">
   <h4 ng-bind="item.title"><small ng-bind="item.pub_date"><strong></strong></small></h4>
   <p ng-bind="item.content"></p>
</div>
```

the item.content and item.content shows respectively. However, the item.pub_date don't show the value in there. I get empty portion at where the date should be in my rendered template.

Using Batarang, I realized the pub_date value shows in the template, but doesn't render or what.

This is how it appears when I look it up in batarang

```
pub_date: 2014-12-05T18:27:30.939Z
```

Do I need to add a date filter to make it work? I'm not exposing the value within the pub_date item properly or? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `{{item.pub_date}}` instead?

Comment: @Blazemonger Nothing shows when I use {{item.pub_date}}

Comment: It should work (http://jsfiddle.net/76o5Lx6b/). Please set up a demo to check.

Comment: I've tried in other html tags, thinking it might be the issue with the <small></small> tag or the <strong></strong> tag. But still, nothing shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `h4` tag wrapping `small` tag which overrides its content. The ngBind directive basically replaces the existing content.

Either move `small` out of `h4` or use double curly notation for the title as:

`<h4>{{item.title}}<small ng-bind="item.pub_date"><strong></strong></small></h4>`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. that's interesting to know. I don't know, but it came naturally to me to nest ng-bind's. But technically, that shouldn't be possible. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For some reason (perhaps conflict with django templating syntax?), when I use <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>, it doesn't display. Batarang still tells me the item.title is in the template, but it doesn't render.

Comment: use `<span ng-bind="item.title"></span>` within `h4` if possible.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. Well, I've been a day now, so will try again, perhaps the timechange will make the code work. Thanks for help.